# Haneke in Swift: Eagerly loading images

Tags: ios, swift, haneke

Is there a way to load an image from an URL and write it directly to the disk cache (without presenting them to an `UIImageView`), so that I can emulate eager loading?

Problems emanate from the need to present 100+ images 4MB each (can't resize them any lower); so we decided to just download all of them into the disk cache, displaying a progress bar to the user, and presenting them after all are in the disk cache.

Any solution that uses [Hanake](https://github.com/Haneke/HanekeSwift) to emulate eager loading will do.

Comment: Image loading library: https://github.com/Haneke/HanekeSwift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you download and save it in a `NSCache` so do something like

```
let cache = NSCache()
cache.setObject(image, forKey: theURLYouDownloadedFrom)
```